# Audio streaming with ajax

Tags: php, audio-streaming

I have a web system (with php) in which I must implement an audio streaming. I have seen many solutions that lead to the use of web-sockets and node.js, but for certain reasons I can not make use of it.

Will there be any way to do it with ajax? That has as recorded, saved on server and that can be consulted by customers. (for example)

Comment: Is this like online radio streaming?

Comment: If as if it were a radio

Comment: In radio streaming, we are using 3rd party radio steaming software (Shout Cast / ICE Cast). You just have to give the Media Streaming Server Link to the Media Player (html 5 media player or flash)... According to my knowledge streaming does not have to do anything with Ajax.

Comment: yes i need the same

Answer (score 2):

Based on your question, I don't think ajax is going to be the solution. The reason being, that ajax is not a continuous stream, but rather a callback between your end users client (browser) and the server. Once the ajax call completes, the connection to the server ends. You may be able to find a drop in jquery solution to play the audio client side, but the best you'll be able to do with ajax is possibly utilize it as a means of delivering files/references to files. For example, you COULD use ajax to call back to the server, get file data and pass back the data to the client side script that handles the audio playback. Also, not sure why this question got a downvote, as it's a perfectly valid question.